# Chrome Emulator Issues | Media Queries

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm testing my responsive website and sadly, the Chrome emulator is not showing the responsive views when I select a device e.g "iPhone 6". The nasty scroll bars appear and looks horrible however, when I resize my browser the breakpoints are working perfectly?

This is how I am defining my breakpoints - the variable $screen-md is set within a variable. I'm using SASS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: $screen-md) { }
```

Here is a screenshot of what's happening in the Chrome Emulator.

[image]

Comment: Have you refreshed after you selected an device? and do you use teh viewport meta tag in the head of your html?

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. The only thing I had found online that may have helped was changing my media queries to max-width rather than min-width but I think this is rubbish...

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue on a new site I didn't code. I found a workaround is in Chrome dev tools, go to the emulation panel (part of the "drawer" tools along with console), and un-check "Emulate Mobile".

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Check if $screen-md is storing 375px since Iphone6 is 375px wide

**2)** Change your min-width to max-width.

**Explanation with example:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px)  {...}
```

above code means "If [device width] is **greater than** or equal to [**375px**], then do {...}"

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px)  {...}
```

above code means "If [device width] is **less than** or equal to [**375px**], then do {...}"

**3)** My personal experience with Chrome is that it sometimes doesn't load the media queries even if you are on the right viewport size. A few times, I had to increase the max-width value by 1 or 2 pixels to make it work. Try that too! Also, don't forget to clear your cache and refresh the page.